# How to run assertion test when JUnit view is empty in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I've been following along a couple of tutorials and at the point where they run the tests in the junit test view in Eclipse, mine just looks disabled, and I can see any tests to run:

[image: Screenshot of Eclipse and JUnit view]

Notice on the right hand side I have an empty JUnit view. None of the tutorials mention anything about this situation. You can see the JUnit library in my Package Explorer too. What do I need to do now to get my test to run in the JUnit test view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got the project setup right, now you need to tell eclipse to execute the test cases locate in the project, for that you need to do the following

> Right click project --> run as --> Junit Test

[image]

And the Junit view of the eclipse will get populated with the test runs as below with the results of which cases failed and which passed

[image]

Comment: Thanks. By that, do you mean right click project (in Package explorer) > Run As > Run configurations... (only option there for me) > select JUnit............. the Run button is disabled. Sorry, I'm a noob with Eclipse and JUnit, but I don't see anything else. Btw I'm on Eclipse 3.8.1 if it helps.

Comment: @Martyn, may be you want to provide a error message or screenshot from a dialog with disabled button. Usually, dialogs explain what is wrong with your configuration,

Comment: OK I see JUnit option in Run As now, I didn't before. I closed down the source files in the editor and opened them again, now I have options (not just "Run as configuration...") such as Java Applet, Java Application, JUnit test. Thanks for your screen shot though, confirmed I'm looking in the correct place.

Answer (score 1):

Just right click on `AssertTest.java`; then follow below--

> run as > Junit Test

Since looking into your screen shot, you only have one Junit class; so it seems this will help you to run Junit.

Answer (score 0):

I found this post while looking into a slightly different "empty JUnit view" issue: after upgrading to Eclipse 2022.06 from 2021.??, my JUnit view stopped working. I could see the unit tests running in the console, but no results were shown in the view.

I was able to fix it by opening the Eclipse preferences Java -> JUnit, then clicking Apply and Close.